# Array function with IndexOf() and splice()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, indexof, splice

I have an array filled with fridge items. I am trying to find the index of particular items and then splice them out of the array and then return the item and console.log the remaining items in the fridge.
I have no clue why it isn't working. I have tried several different variations and I have tried looking at other similar answers for this question. Any advice or help is much appreciated.

```
fridge = ["milk", "cheese", "butter"];

function removeItemFromFridge(item) {
  
  if (item.indexOf()) {
    fridge.splice(item);
    return item;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
removeItemFromFridge("milk");
removeItemFromFridge("butter");

console.log(fridge);
```

Comment: `if (item.indexOf()) {`?? Shouldn't it be `if (fridge.indexOf(item)) {`?? This will not solve this, there are more issues..

Comment: You can use `filter` method of Array to remove a specific item.

Comment: @IhorTkachuk, of course, technically, `filter` doesn't remove an item from an array, it creates a new array.

Comment: @Wyck But, modifying outer scope is bad practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexOf finds the first index that matches the given value in the array, if no such value is present it returns -1. for splice you specify the first index from where you want to start deleting and in the second argument you pass the number of element you want to delete starting from given index in first argument.
I think you want to do it like this way

```
let fridge = ["milk", "cheese", "butter"];

function removeItemFromFridge(item) {
  const index = fridge.indexOf(item);
  
  if (index > -1 ) {
    fridge.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
removeItemFromFridge("milk");
removeItemFromFridge("butter");

console.log(fridge);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I get what I was doing wrong now by looking at your answer. It worked as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If `fridge` is a value we can replace entirely instead of modifying the existing array, you can use `array.filter()` instead.

```
function removeItemFromFridge(item) {
  fridge = fridge.filter(v => v !== item)
}
```

Otherwise, if you do want to preserve that same array, you can find the item index and splice it off.

```
function removeItemFromFridge(item) {
  const index = fridge.indexOf(item);
  if (index !== -1) fridge.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Also, doing a `return` is not needed since your caller isn't using the returned value.

Comment: you have written item.indexOf(item) , how is it correct, shouldn't it be fridge.indexOf(item)?

Comment: Yes it should be that. I just put in what I last had. I had it that originally and then started to play around with it and forgot to change it back to fridge.indexOf(item)

Comment: Thank you so much. You all helped tremendously.